# NSRunLoop scoped variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Sometimes I find myself needing to add flagstyle `iVars` to `viewControllers`.

For example, if the user changes focus from one `UITextField` to another, `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` on the new field will be called before `textFieldDidEndEditing` on the old field.

If I, for some reason, need to know in `textFieldDidEndEditing`  which field will be in focus next, I set a flag, `tagnumberForNextTextField`, in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, which can be checked right after by `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

Now, the problem is, that this design creates buggy code, because it is often hard to make sure that the flag gets reset when it is no longer relevant.

Ideally, I would never need to use these dreaded flags, but if I do need them, **is there a way to make sure that an `iVar` (or `property`) gets reset at the end of the current run loop?** (You could compare this with a request scoped variable in a web application).

Is it possible? Is it advisable?

**EDIT, here is some example code:**

```
@interface MyController()
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tagForTextFieldThatWillBeginEditing;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secondTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *thirdTextField;
@end

@implementation MyController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tagForTextFieldThatWillBeginEditing = -1;
}

// This will be called for the new field, before textFieldDidEndEditing is called for the old field
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    self.tagForTextFieldThatWillBeginEditing = textField.tag;
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (self.firstTextField == textField && self.tagForTextFieldThatWillBeginEditing == self.thirdTextField.tag) {
        // Do something special when jumping straight from first to third field, maybe show an alertview or whatever
    } 
    // Here, I can reset the flag
    self.tagForTextFieldThatWillBeginEditing = -1;    
}
@end
```

But this can create nasty bugs. What if the user backs out of the view controller or does something else unexpected, that will prevent the *textFieldDidEndEditing* from being called? In that case, the flag is not reset. In this particular case it may not become a problem, because the flag is always set in *textFieldShouldBeginEditing*, but it doesn't really matter.
The main problem is that if I use flags, it's easy to create bugs by not resetting them correctly in every corner case of viewcontroller execution.

Would it make sense to have a runloop scoped flag? Or is it too unpredictable to be sure exactly what will be done in the same runloop?

Comment: Wouldn't it not be equally dangerous to rely on the fact that textFieldShouldBeginEditing on the new field is called before textFieldDidEndEditing, and that both calls occur in the same run loop iteration?

Comment: Can you please add your code as well?

Comment: Hi,

I've been using [self performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:] with a delay of 0.0 for similar tasks (apologies for incorrect syntax; am on iPhone). Unless someone can correct me, I believe that a delay of zero will mean the selector is performed as the last thing in the run-loop. So maybe you could make a method that resets your flags and is called in this manner....?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! I thought the order of events were always the same? Or are they actually racing each other? In this particular case, wouldn't they be called within the same run loop?

Comment: @Hunkpapa: I don't know! It was just a remark because your concept seemed fragile to me. - It would probably help if you describe more in detail what you are actually trying to achieve (including your current code).

Comment: @MartinR, I edited the post with some example code. I agree that it may be a very fragile solution. That's why I asked you guys :)

Comment: @Todd I thought performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:0 just put the call in the run queue, so it would be executed by the next runloop?

Comment: It looks like you are fighting the framework. Maybe there is another way to obtain what you are after? In the question's current form you have already decided the solution you want, but it also looks like it is not a good fit for the framework, so if you could describe your goals, then somebody might be able to suggest a solution that better fits the responder chain of Cocoa Touch.

Comment: @Monolo Yes, it really does feel like I'm fighting the framework :) The actual implementation is a rather complex viewcontroller with three text fields, where the text fields can be updated both by tapping the fields (and using the keybaord), but also by using buttons with predefined strings that is shown in a three-page scrollview beneath the textfields.
So, I need to display the correct ScrollView page whenever a textfield is tapped. I also need to switch focus of the textfields when scrolling or tapping a scrollview button. Simply put, it's a myriad of execution paths :/

Comment: Now, months later, I heard of https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa which solves these problems with state flags etc in a very elegant way